# JPA and QueryDSL projections against entities with a class hierachy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a set of entities that belong to a particular class hierarchy (each class in this hierarchy maps backs to the same table in the database). I'm attempting to project the data the class hierarchy represents using QueryDSL. The projection needs to return fields from each of the concrete classes but I"m not sure how to do this properly or if it's even possible.

I have something that sort of works but the fields that exist in the concrete class aren't projected properly, the results returned are duplicated and the query that is generated joins multiple times against the same table.

An example of what I have is (I'm excluding getters/setters/contructors and the majority of the hibernate annotations for berevety).

Is what I'm trying to do at all possible while have it return the results that I want and a normal query?

```
public abstract class AbstractLocation {

    @Id
    private int id;

}

public class Municipality extends AbstractLocation {

    private String municipality;

}

public class Address extends AbstractLocation {

    private String buildingAddress;

}

public class LocationDTO {

    private int id;

    private String municipality;

    private String buildingAddress;

}

public void getLocationDTO() {
    final QAbstractLocation location = new QAbstractLocation("abstractCase");
    final QMunicipality municipality = new QMunicipality("sampleUnitBasedCase");
    final QAddress address = new QAddress("listingCase");

    final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(this.getEntityManager());

    return query.from(location, municipality, address)
            .list(new QLocationDTO(
                    location.id,
                    municipality.municipality,
                    address.buildingAddress));
}
```